# JSON using Jackson Library same object`s fields but printing different values when nessecary

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, annotations

I want you to look at only the PlasticInfo part of the json data below. As you can see, in one part it outputs only 2 values, while in the other part it outputs 3 values.

The thing that confuses me is whether they are separate-objects or the same object just did this using special annotation? If it's the same object, what annotation can I use? So how can I do the following part using the same object? Let's say they are the same object and have 3 variables, in this part I want it to output 2 when necessary, in the other part I want it to print 3 values.

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "Successfully processed",
  "result": {
    "ContractRs": {
      "Contract": {
        "OrderDprt": "",
        "ClientType": "",
        "ClientCategory": "",
        "ContractIDT": {
          "ContractNumber": "",
          "RBSNumber": "",
          "Client": {
            "OrderDprt": "",
            "ClientType": "",
            "ClientCategory": "",
            "ClientInfo": {
              "ClientNumber": "",
              "RegNumber": "",
              "ShortName": "   ",
              "FirstName": "",
              "LastName": "",
              "MiddleName": " ",
              "SecurityName": "",
              "Country": "",
              "MaritalStatus": "",
              "BirthDate": "",
              "BirthPlace": ""
            },
            "PlasticInfo": {
              "FirstName": "",
              "LastName": ""
            },
            "PhoneList": {
              "Phone": {
                "PhoneType": "",
                "PhoneNumber": ""
              }
            },
            "DateOpen": "",
            "BaseAddress": {
              "City": "",
              "PostalCode": "",
              "AddressLine1": ""
            }
          }
        },
        "Currency": "",
        "ContractName": "",
        "Product": {
          "AddInfo": {
            "Parm": {
              "ParmCode": "",
              "Value": ""
            }
          }
        },
        "ProductionParms": {
          "CardExpiry": "",
          "SequenceNumber": ""
        },
        "PlasticInfo": {
          "FirstName": "",
          "LastName": "",
          "CompanyName": ""
        },
        "DateOpen": "",
        "AddContractInfo": {
          "ExtraRs": ""
        }
      },
      "Info": {
        "Status": {
          "StatusClass": "",
          "StatusCode": "",
          "StatusDetails": "",
          "ProductionStatus": ""
        },
        "Balances": [
          {
            "Name": "",
            "Type": "",
            "Amount": 0,
            "Currency": ""
          },
          {
            "Name": "",
            "Type": "",
            "Amount": 0.00,
            "Currency": ""
          }
        ],
        "RiskGroup": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One possibility is this: There is a configuration in Jackson to indicate "Ignore null values during serialization". It might be enabled somewhere in the configuration. One way to do it is `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion( JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL )`. You may want to check.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem, which what I actually want is the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation, which ignore specified fields.